adDidDismissFullScreenContent for rewarded ads not triggered
Had the same problem as described here: link to the question I found
I use both func presentInterstitialAd(fromRootViewController viewController: UIViewController)and func presentRewardedAd(fromRootViewController viewController: UIViewController).
Ideally, this should work for both rewardAd and interstitialAd:
    // MARK: - GADFullScreenContentDelegate Methods
        public func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error)
        {
            print("Ad did fail to present full screen content with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        public func adWillPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd)
        {
            print("Ad will present full screen content.")
        }
        
        public func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) 
        {
            print("Ad did dismiss full screen content.")
        } 
    

I noticed, that adDidDismissFullScreenContentis not triggered after rewardedAd is presented.

Workaround I used it to use
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) (is triggered before ad is shown) and override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)is triggred once add is closed.
